# How to pause Python code and constantly check a specific Excel cell, and when it is non-empty then continue with rest of code

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd, xlwings

I am using Python, with the pandas, xlwings, and openpyxl packages. The excel file is being updated by something outside of Python which will Output a large range a Sheet 1, A2:H70000. I would like to have a piece of code that is constantly checking Sheet 1, F3, an empty Excel cell F3, and when it becomes non-empty, then go on with the rest of the Python code. The next step after that is loading a dataframe which I have already figured out.
I've tried this code but the entire code executes at once in Pycharm.

I can read that the F3 cell is None, but don't know how to pause the code until F3 is no longer None

```html
Test = ws['F3']
sum is None
while sum is None:
    sum = sum + Test.value
```

Comment: A while loop with time.sleep for a polling interval should do. You likely want to reopen the file on each check. You can also level up to have the file system detect when a file is modified. There are multiple ways to do this, so internet search time.

Comment: You can't do this. The file format does not allow for changes to be made, the file must be overwritten every time.